# Negating logical values from input in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am confused why I am getting `Error: invalid argument type` when I negate a logical value from `input` in the `server()` function of a Shiny app. In the minimal example below, `input[['log_scale']]` is clearly a logical (Boolean) variable but the statement `if(!input[['log_scale']])` fails. Removing the negation operator `!` makes the code work but for my actual app I want to be able to include conditional statements negating some logical values passed to `server()` from the `input` argument.

**EDIT**: I tried to follow the suggestion of YBS to use `==FALSE` instead of `!`. This still causes issues if I have multiple conditions in my `if` statement separated with `&`. See reprex below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel('Test'),
  
  # Sidebar with options
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("foo",
                   "foo",
                   c('Yes' = TRUE,
                     'No' = FALSE)),

      radioButtons('log_scale',
                   'Log-transform y-axis?',
                   c('Yes' = TRUE,
                     'No' = FALSE)),
      
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 10^(1:5))
    if (input[['foo']] & input[['log_scale']] == FALSE) title = "log scale plot" else title = "not log scale plot"
    if (input[['log_scale']] == FALSE) z = '' else z = 'y'

    plot(dat$x, dat$y, log = z, main = title)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use `if (input[['log_scale']]==FALSE) z = '' else z = 'y'`

Comment: Argh, that works in the reprex but didn't work in my actual code. I get `Error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`. Even though I am sure that my input value is a logical. Am I missing something? I may need to find a better reprex.

Comment: @YBS I found that the problematic behavior occurs when multiple conditions separated with `&` are passed to if statement, even if I use `==FALSE`. I've edited the example to reflect this.

Comment: OK I think the solution is to use `input[['foo']] == TRUE & input[['log_scale']] == FALSE`, in other words to write all the conditions out fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radioButtons` produces character type values, so doing type casting fixes the problem.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel('Test'),
    
    # Sidebar with options
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons("foo",
                         "foo",
                         c(TRUE = 'yes',
                          FALSE = 'no')),
            radioButtons('log_scale',
                         'Log-transform y-axis?',
                         c('Yes' = TRUE,
                           'No' = FALSE)),
            
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput('plot')
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        
        dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 10^(1:5))
        if (as.logical(input[['foo']]) & !as.logical(input[['log_scale']])) title = "log scale plot" else title = "not log scale plot"
        if (!as.logical(input[['log_scale']])) z = '' else z = 'y'
        
        plot(dat$x, dat$y, log = z, main = title)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: OK that makes a lot of sense. I guess an even better solution would be to use checkbox for the yes/no options to get a logical value.